# Errors Working with Entity Framework Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can anyone tell me why the following code doesn't work?

```
IQueryable query = from pr in Repository.Query<ProviderRanking>()
                   orderby pr.ProviderRankingFlags.Any(), pr.TimestampUtc
                   select pr;

int count = query.Count();
IEnumerable<ProviderRanking> reviews = query.ToList();
```

The last two lines produce the errors:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I was thinking that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All LINQ methods (except `Cast` and `OfType`) extend generic collection interfaces.

You need to declare your variable as the generic `IQueryable<T>` interface.
(or just use `var` to infer that automatically.)

Comment: Or be lazy and declare it with `var`.

Comment: Do'h! Of course, I didn't look there. I could even use `var query =...`. Thanks.